# iReport Designer - dynamic list and page number

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I have put a list inside a rectangle with *Relative to Tallest Object* property which is inside a frame with *Float* property. All the components are inside the detail band. The size of the list component depends on the list which is sent from my Java application. 
When I print a report with 100 objects inside a list, all records are not printed inside a rectangle. I don not know how I can fix it. Just the first page has a rectangle.

Also, I have a problem with page number. I put the page number variable at the bottom of the detail band with maximum height, but it is printed just on the first page. On other pages there is no any page number.

It would great if someone can help me.

Comment: You should post the *jrxml* file

Comment: Put your page number in your page footer.